# Redirect an entire directory on a WP site to a new domain, with a few subdirectory exceptions

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect an entire directory on a WP site to a directory on a new domain, with a few subdirectory exceptions that exist on the new domain.

e.g.

```
Redirect /2012/ to newdomain.com/blog
Redirect /2012/subdirectory to newdomain.com/2012/subdirectory
```

This is what I have that is not working:

```
#blanket redirect with exceptions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2012/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}
!^/2012/(\/2012\/subdirectory1\/|\/2012\/subdirectory2\/|\/2012\/subdirectory1\/)
RewriteRule ^/?2012/(.+)$ http://www.newdomain.com/blog/ [L,R=301]

#redirecting the exceptions
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old-domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^\/2012\/subdirectory1\/$
"http\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.com\/2012\/subdirectory1\/" [R=301,L]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want something simple:

```
RewriteRule ^2012/$ http://www.newdomain.com/blog/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^2012/subdirectory/?$ http://www.newdomain.com/blog/subdirectory/ [L,R=301]
```

Or maybe:

```
RewriteRule ^2012/(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

These rules need to be **before** any wordpress rules in your htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is still redirecting all of the 2012/subdirectories to newdomain.com/blog/, even with that second rule. Any other ideas?

Comment: @user2763413 the first rule *only* redirects a request to `/2012/` or a request to `/2012/subdirectory/`. Nothing else, not even `/2012/file.txt`.

Comment: I did use that second rule you supplied: `RewriteRule ^2012/(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301]`

It's not redirecting the "exceptions" correctly. They are still being redirected like all other /2012/subdirectories. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user2763413 the second rule redirects everything, the first 2 doesn't

Comment: I apologize if I am not explaining myself clearly. This is redirecting `/2012/subdirectory1` to `http://www.newdomain.com/blog` when I want it to redirect to `http://www.newdomain.com/2012/subdirectory1`. I only want that to happen for a few subdirectories though, and the rest to be redirected to `http://www.newdomain.com/blog`.

Comment: @MikeT No idea why `/2012/subdirectory` is redirecting to `http://www.newdomain.com/blog`, the rule clearly states the **only** `^2012/$` gets redirected. If there's anything after 2012, the rule doesn't match. This all works (not the rule after "Or Maybe", obviously that's not what you want) in my blank htaccess file.

Comment: I want all subdirectories of `2012` to be redirected to `newdomain.com/blog` except for a few. I want the exceptions to be redirected to the same directories on the new domain. Some pages will have a replacement on the new domain and others will not.

Comment: @MikeT Then you want the 2nd rule, followed by the third without the `$1`

Comment: I think I finally have it straight. Thank you for your help.